# joint p.d.f. of stationary time series variables

Tags: time-series

if a stationary time series verifies that each variable depends only on the variable before it, and the joint p.d.f. of $x_i$ and $x_{i-1}$ is $f(x_{i-1},x_i)$,
which is the joint p.d.f. of $x_i,x_{i+1},x_{i+2}$, and of $x_i,x_{i+1},x_{i+2},x_{i+3}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(a,b,c) &= f_{X_3\mid X_1,X_2}(c\mid X_1 = a,X_2=b)\cdot f_{X_1,X_2}(a,b)\\
&= f_{X_3\mid X_2}(c\mid X_2=b)\cdot f_{X_1,X_2}(a,b) & {\scriptstyle\text{by assumption}}\\
&= f_{X_3\mid X_2}(c\mid X_2=b)\cdot f_{X_2\mid X_1}(b\mid X_1=a)\cdot f_{X_1}(a)
\end{align}$$
in which you know the first two terms on the right side of the last expression. Do you know
the last one?

The calculations for four variables are just an extended version of the calculation given
above.